# Failed to parse the row anko kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

i dont know why this code can't parse the row. please help.

```
private var dataCards :MutableList<DataCard> = mutableListOf()
btn_read.setOnClickListener {
        showAllCardData()
        var data = dataCards
        tvResult.text = ""

        for (i in 0..(data.size - 1)) {
            tvResult.append(data.get(i).id.toString() + " " +
                    data.get(i).title + " " +
                    data.get(i).instruction + " " +
                    data.get(i).level + " " +
                    data.get(i).rewardPoint + " " +
                    data.get(i).rewardExp + " " +
                    data.get(i).inputdate + "\n")
        }
    }
private fun showAllCardData(){
    missionDB.use {
        val result = select(DataCard.TABLE_USERCARD)
        val cards = result.parseList(classParser<DataCard>())
        dataCards.addAll(cards)

    }
}
```

Any reference or suggestion ?, the error is "failed to parse the row" please help.

Comment: where your code is failing ? what exception are you getting ?

Comment: @crgarridos 07-20 18:20:41.222 9160-9160/com.brid.azis.vipgame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.brid.azis.vipgame, PID: 9160
    org.jetbrains.anko.AnkoException: Class parser for com.brid.azis.vipgame.test.DataModel.DataCard failed to parse the row: [1, 5, Membaca Brailee Huruf Konsonan 5, Silahkan pelajari kartu ini, Lalu setelah itu silahkan ke gurumu dan bacalah di depannya. Semangaat !, 1, 1, 17, 2, 20-07-2018, 0, ] (constructor parameter types: [java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.I

Comment: show us your DataCard class

Answer (score 0):

row you get from `showAllCardData` function not match with **DataCard**,

example row you get from database `(field1,field2)`
but your **Datacard** constructor parameter `(field1,field2,field3,field4)`